# Cannot subscript a value of type NSMutableDictionary with an index of type String

Tags: ios, swift

I am also facing the same issue mentioned above. Can someone help me on     that? 
I have defined my `NSMutableDictionary` as results. And by printing it I got the result as below:

Below is the values in "**results**" `NSMutableDictionary`.

`[{Name = 4480101010;Feedback = goo;FeedbackID = 186;FeedbackOn = "18-Mar-2016 11:26";IsFrom = 1;UserName = "Bernie Killian";RequestID = 1531;}`

```
{Name = 4480101010;Feedback = supr;FeedbackID = 172;FeedbackOn = "09-Mar-2016 08:04";IsFrom = 1;UserName = rajesh;RequestID = 1445;},{Name = 4480101010;Feedback = supr;FeedbackID = 170;FeedbackOn = "09-Mar-2016 08:00";IsFrom = 1;UserName = rajesh;RequestID = 1444;},{Name = 4480101010;Feedback = "all works fine";FeedbackID = 158;FeedbackOn = "08-Mar-2016 17:21";IsFrom = 1;UserName = "Mahendra Suthar";RequestID = 1429;}]
```

I need to populate these values in table view in such a way that the Name should be in the nameLabel cell value, feedback in `feedbackLabel` cell value. How to do that? I have tried all the possible things. But not able to get the solution.

This is my full code.

import Foundation
class FeedbackViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var feedbackResults = [String]()
var prefectCount : Int = 0
var abhyasiCount : Int = 0
var prefectResults = [NSMutableDictionary]()
var abhyasiResults = [NSMutableDictionary]()
var selectedIndex : Int = 0
var totalCount : Int = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    reloadTable()
    let appid : String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("appID") as! String
    Server.sendGet(URL.getUserFeedbackInformation(appid), completionHandler: self.feedbackCompletionHandler)
}

@IBAction func onFeedbackChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }else{
        self.selectedIndex = 1
    }
    print(selectedIndex)
}

func feedbackCompletionHandler(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // code here
        let responseStr = Server.dataToNSArray(data)
        for eachFeedback in responseStr!{
            if eachFeedback["IsFromPerceptor"] as! NSNumber == 1   {
                self.abhyasiCount++
                self.abhyasiResults.append(eachFeedback as! NSMutableDictionary)

            }
            else
            {
                self.prefectCount++
                self.prefectResults.append(eachFeedback as! NSMutableDictionary)

            }
        }

        self.reloadTable()

    })

}

// START Table View
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.selectedIndex)
    if self.selectedIndex == 0 {
        self.totalCount = self.abhyasiCount
    }else{
        self.totalCount =  self.prefectCount
    }
    return self.totalCount

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedbackIdentifierCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedbackIdentifierCell
    cell.numberLabel.text = abhyashiResults[“FeedbackID”] as? String
    cell.nameLabel.text = abhyashiResults[“Name”] as? String
    cell.feedbackLabel.text = abhyashiResults[“Feedback”] as? String
    cell.dateLabel.text = abhyashiResults[“FeedbackOn”] as? String

    return cell

}

func reloadTable() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: There is no issue "mentioned above".  What problem are you having?

Comment: In this,I'm trying to access from "results" & move it to below function. func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedbackIdentifierCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedbackIdentifierCell
cell.numberLabel.text = self.results["Feedback"] as? String  // I need to populate all the Feedback in the tableview. But getting error as "Cannot subscript a value of type NSMutableDictionary with an index of type String"
 return cell
    }

Comment: Check class type of result. I think it is may be array.

Comment: I have checked it. I have declared the type as NSMutableDictionary only.

Comment: your result is Array ... not Dictionary ...

Comment: Okay. Can you mention how to do it?

Comment: can u show ur allocation on array ,and data in objc format

Comment: I am having everything in Swift only. I dont know objC

Comment: I edited and posted my full code here.

Answer (score 0):

The results value you have provided is an array of dictionaries and not a dictionary itself.  Based on your comment it looks like you need to pull a particular value out of the array.  You would *probably* do this based on the index path that is passed to you:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedbackIdentifierCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedbackIdentifierCell

    let valueForCell = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.numberLabel.text = valueForCell["Feedback"]
    …
```